# XSLT output does not reflect on Firefox

Tags: firefox, xslt, transformation

I have created a Practice.xsl file to transform the source Practice.xml to an html from javascript and add the generated html to n empty DIV element, which is working fine with IE
But same html is not rendered correctly on Firefox.

here is the Practice.xml

```
<feed>
 <feedback>
  <user>Naresh</user>
  <date>12 Oct, 2009</date>
  <comments>This blog has no stuff to rate it</comments>
 </feedback>
 <feedback>
  <user>Pokuri</user>
  <date>21 Dec, 2009</date>
  <comments>Naresh is right</comments>
 </feedback>
 <feedback>
  <user>Subbu</user>
  <date>30 Dec, 2009</date>
  <comments>I don't agree with both Naresh n Pokuri</comments>
 </feedback>
</feed>
```

Here is the Practice.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="feed/feedback">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Feedback Forum</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <span style="display:block; padding: 5px 10px; background-color: #C9F0F9; width: 100%; margin-top:10px; border-left:10px solid #F9EBC9; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"><xsl:apply-templates select="user"/> on <xsl:apply-templates select="date"/></span>
 <span style="display:block; padding: 5px 10px; background-color: #CDF5CD; width: 100%; border-left:10px solid #F9EBC9;"><xsl:apply-templates select="comments"/></span>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the javascript for work with XSLT transformations on Firefox

```
function listOrders(){ 
 var XSLT = loadXSLT("Practice.xsl");
 var trasformedText;
 if(window.ActiveXObject){
  trasformedText = XMLDOM.transformNode(XSLT);
  document.getElementById("rightDIV").innerHTML=trasformedText;
 } else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){
  **xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(XSLT);
  trasformedText = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(XMLDOM, document);
  document.getElementById("rightDIV").appendChild(trasformedText);**
 } else {
  alert("Sorry your browser may not support xsl transformation.\n+Please check your browser documentation for further help");
 }

}
```

---

Relative images for professionals to identify the problem easily

In Firefox:
http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/8509/firefoxk.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Might be the slowness of Firefox in loading xsl file. So I made following code changes to cope with it, which i have ignored as the files are small.

wrote the statement
XMLDOM.async=false;
XSLT.async=false;

```
function loadXML(){
    var XMLDOM;
    // if it is IE
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        XMLDOM = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            // following staement added
        XMLDOM.async=false;
        XMLDOM.load("Practice.xml");
    } else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){       
        XMLDOM = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
            // following staement added
        XMLDOM.async=false;
        XMLDOM.load("Practice.xml");
    } else {
        alert("Sorry your browser may not support loading an external file.\n+Please check your browser documentation for further help");
    }
    return XMLDOM;
}

function loadXSLT(xsltFile){
    var XSLT;
    // if it is IE
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        XSLT = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                // following staement added
        XSLT.async=false;
        XSLT.load(xsltFile);
    } else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){       
        XSLT = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                // following staement added
        XSLT.async=false;
        XSLT.load(xsltFile);
    } else {
        alert("Sorry your browser may not support loading an external file.\n+Please check your browser documentation for further help");
    }
    return XSLT;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

View the generated HTML source. Does it look right? You're displaying a complete `<html>` page for **each** `feedback` instead of displaying only the `<span>`s for each `feedback`.

Your XSL needs to be altered with a `<xsl:for-each>` for each feedback:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="feed">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Feedback Forum</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <xsl:for-each select="feedback">
  <span style="display:block; padding: 5px 10px; background-color: #C9F0F9; width: 100%; margin-top:10px; border-left:10px solid #F9EBC9; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"><xsl:apply-templates select="user"/> on <xsl:apply-templates select="date"/></span>
  <span style="display:block; padding: 5px 10px; background-color: #CDF5CD; width: 100%; border-left:10px solid #F9EBC9;"><xsl:apply-templates select="comments"/></span>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IE is too forgiving in displaying multiple `<html>`s in one response, that's why it worked in this browser. Firefox more strictly adheres the standards: there can be only **one** `<html>` element in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah I am generating only span tags right now. But that doesn't work. If i debug the script using Firebug in Firefox, then it reflects the transformation properly. How come that is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't really answer the question, but client-side xslt transform is pretty dicey and you're not guaranteed much consistency.  I would consider using server side XSLT transformation if I were you.

Comment: Interesting point of view, XSLT 1.0 is pretty straight forward with little room for ambiguity.  Whats the source of your opinion?  Can you point to any examples of inconsistency?